# Alphabetical Order for Customer name is not working properly by mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have sorted customer name in alphabetical order and displayed as checkbox list in a page by below mysql query,

```
SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE customer_status ='1' order by customer_name ASC
```

But this query result the output "A.G.S Stores" after "Z Mart" wrongly as below,

```
White Field Super Market
Xpress Mart
Yellow Bell Super Bazar
Z Mart
A.G.S Stores
A.N.S. Pandian Super Market
A.R Super Market
Aadithan Traders
```

Can anyone give solution for this issue?

Comment: That's a list of customer names?

Comment: this query result the output "A.G.S Stores" after "Z Mart" wrongly

Comment: SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE customer_status ='1' order by customer_name ;

Comment: Yes ,these are all the list of customer store names,saved in customer_name field in table,ascending order query not working properly

Comment: What do you get if use: `order by trim(customer_name) ASC` ?

Comment: Or use `order by SUBSTITUTE(customer_name, " ", "") ASC`

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos I added trim,this issue has been solved.Thank you so much all of you stawberry ,  Akshay Rohilla, Alive to Die.

Comment: Special Thanks to @Giorgos Betsos

Answer (score 2):

`[ASC]` is by default. What u can do is use DESC check if is sorting in desc order than remove desc from order by and use order by with ASC or omit `ASC`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer,I solved this issue by above comment - order by trim(customer_name) ASC

Comment: I know that you can't comment, but that doesn't mean that you add a comment as an answer.

Comment: @user3157334  did you tried  `order by SUBSTITUTE(customer_name, " ", "") ASC`?

Comment: Now it changed to zero

Answer (score 1):

Hello I tried you data in mysql having MYISAM Engine For Table ,

please check my results in  image it is correct .

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my table,there was above 500 customer names.So I faced this issue and solved by trim keyword like this order by trim(customer_name) ASC